# Retrieve a CSS attribute with Javascript, then write it to a CSS file on the server

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that has a theme that injects a tiny bit of CSS with Javascript at the very end of the page load. This results in a sudden visual change when the Javascript finally executes. I can't modify the Javascript. And I can't just add the injected CSS to my own stylesheet which is loaded much earlier to make sure they match up, as the values may change every once in a while.

So what I'm looking for is a way to use a bit of Javascript to grab the two injected CSS values, see if they match what's already in the CSS file - and if they do not match, write a couple lines of CSS to the CSS file with the values retrieved earlier. Or - rewrite the old CSS lines incase it had written some CSS in the past which no longer matches the injected values.
The Theme-injected values change every once in a while due to user customization - thus needing something that can dynamically correct for that.

I'm assuming I'll probably have to do this in conjunction with PHP somehow. JQuery can also be used if necessary.

My knowledge on both PHP and Javascript is fairly limited.

Comment: Way too broad..

Answer (score 0):

you can use get css attribute & change the val to getComputedStyle().

```
var element = document.getElementById('test_id'),
style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
padding = style.getPropertyValue('padding').val='15px';
```

Html

```
<div id="test_id">hello  testing</div>
```

CSS

```
#test_id{
   position: absolute;
   padding: 5px;   
}
```

Check this demo [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kalpesh8/d5ns66qn/)